# Optimization of recursion in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a recursive function. And I want to optimize it as less as 10 sec. Higher use of Memory is not an issue.

Currently, it takes around **85 sec on Linux** and three times more on Mac.

I could not understand in what way I can proceed?

Here is code:

```
using namespace std;

double get_wall_time(){
    struct timeval time;
    if (gettimeofday(&time,NULL)){
        //  Handle error
        return 0;
    }
    return (double)time.tv_sec + (double)time.tv_usec * .000001;
}

int fun(long long n) {

    if (n < 0) {
        cout << "Please enter valid number";
        return 0;
    }

    else if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return 1;

    else if (n % 2 == 0)
        return fun(n / 2);

    else if (n % 2 == 1)
        return fun(n / 2) + fun(n / 2 - 1);

    else
        return 0;
}

int main() {
    double begin = get_wall_time();
    cout << fun(123456789012345678) << std::endl;
    double end = get_wall_time();
    cout << "Time elapsed : " << double(end - begin);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
If n is even, return `f(n/2)`
If n is odd, return `f(n/2)+f(n/2-1)`

Comment: Just to double check, did you compile with optimizations turned on?

Comment: `else if (n % 2)` and `else if (n % 2 + 1)`. Are you sure you meant that? If `n` is odd, you want to `return fun(n / 2)`? And the second else-if there will always be true because `n` is positive

Comment: Either `n %2` or `n % 2 + 1` will always be true, you'll never get to the final `else` clause.

Comment: The way to optimize a function like this is with memoization.

Comment: @NathanOliver what do you mean by 'Optimization turned on'? How to do it?

Comment: @Barmar how to do it with memorization? Any links for tutorial, example ?

Comment: @user252514 like `g++ -O2 main.cpp`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: @user252514 Compiler optimizations are where the compiler will modify your code such that it would produce the same observable behavior but with better performances. Each compiler has it's own flags and options to control this behavior.

Comment: Guys, please do not give downvotes. I do not how to do it, that's why I asked a question.

I am a beginner just don't discourage to ask questions. :(

Comment: @jamesdlin My bad. I corrected typo.

Comment: the other question is - what is this algorithm supposed to calculate, the best fix to most perf issues like this is not micro optimizing but choosing a better algorithm, quick sort vs bubble sort, sieve vs brute force for prime detection etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the results using a `std::map`, like so:

```
std::map<long long, int>fun_results;
int fun(long long n) {
    try {
        return fun_results.at(n);
    } catch(const std::out_of_range&) {

        if (n < 0) {
            cout << "Please enter valid number";
            return 0;
        }

        else if (n == 0 || n == 1)
            return fun_results[n] = 1;

        else if (n % 2 == 0)
            return fun_results[n] = fun(n / 2);

        else if (n % 2 == 1)
            return fun_results[n] = fun(n / 2) + fun(n / 2 - 1);

        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
1332403
Time elapsed : 0.000710011
```

Comment: Can you give me guidance how does it work, why it's so fast?

Comment: Not better than the Wikipedia articles on [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) and [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). In short, your algorithm computes the same intermediate results over and over again. By storing the partial results, we save zillions of recursive calls.

Comment: Thanks, Rob, That's what I want to know, keywords to search and learn like here, Dynamic programming.

-ve marking without giving proper answer makes me depressed. :(

Comment: What conditions cause the final `else` to be executed?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - provably, nothing. But I wanted to match OP as closely as possible.